# GCC --target triplet for HP-UX

Tags: gcc, compilation, hp-ux

I want to compile GCC and binutils which would produce 64bit executables.
From [GNU documents](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html) I've found out that it must look like ia64-*-hpux*.

For ia64-hp-hpux11*, the default output type is 32bit:

```
 % file ./a.out
 ./a.out:        ELF-32 executable object file - IA64
```

That is what I have:

```
 % uname -s -r -v -m
 HP-UX B.11.31 U ia64
```

So what woluld be 64bit target triplet for ia64-hpux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the GCC manual:

```
-milp32
-mlp64
    Generate code for a 32-bit or 64-bit environment. The 32-bit environment
sets int, long and pointer to 32 bits. The 64-bit environment sets int to 32
bits and long and pointer to 64 bits. These are HP-UX specific flags.
```

So you need to pass '-mlp64' to GCC. I'm not sure if there is a separate triplet that would automatically turn this on, but you can always add your own CFLAGS when compiling.